# Wake up waiting thread on touch event from activity?

Tags: android

I have this thread wating for onTouchEvent()

```
private Runnable disconnectCallback = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    // Perform any required operation on disconnect
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Your session expired Please Login again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                final Logout l=new Logout();
                l.setContext(Ac2.this);// passing context of Ac3.java to Logout.java
                l.execute(sessid,uname);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

what i want is notify this waiting thread when user touches a mobile screen..

Answer (score 0):

```
private Runnable disconnectCallback = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Perform any required operation on disconnect
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Your session expired Please Login again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    synchronized (disconnectCallback) {
                        disconnectCallback.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                final Logout l = new Logout();
                l.setContext(Ac2.this);// passing context of Ac3.java to
                                        // Logout.java
                l.execute(sessid, uname);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

and in onTouch event call:

```
    disconnectCallback.notifyAll();
```

Comment: It gives following error:java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()

Comment: call wait also on disconnectCallback like: disconnectCallback.wait();

Comment: btw i would suggest to move wait related code outside run on UI thread.

Comment: Following error occurs: Activity done(in application MyapplicationName)Not Responding

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private Runnable disconnectCallback = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Perform any required operation on disconnect
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Your session expired Please Login again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        try {
            synchronized(disconnectCallback){
            disconnectCallback.wait();
            final Logout l=new Logout();
            l.setContext(Ac2.this);// passing context of Ac3.java to Logout.java
            l.execute(sessid,uname);

            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
};
```

Inside onTouch

```
synchronized (disconnectCallback) {
        disconnectCallback.notify();
    }
```

Comment: Are you doing any UI related task inside logout?

Comment: Following error occurs: Activity done(in application MyapplicationName)Not Responding

Comment: In Logout.java It calls a php file and moves to login screen(Previous Activity)